How to remove white corners from every page in pdf file?
Is there a way to round corners for every page in pdf file?
Is there any tool to do it automatically? There is 186 pages.


I think the best way would be to add a black rectangle line with fitting rounded edges to each page (width and height should be a little higher than the page outline, so it stays invisible).
I don't know of a way to alter the page bounds to something other than rectangular.
For automation... Idk, PDFSam maybe. One way to go would be to extract all images, edit them (could also be a floodfill with black in the corners) and combine as pdf again. This might be a mission for imageMagick and pdfToolkit. But I did not test it out.
